# What does this print in C and how?

Tags: c, printing, output

I'm confused about how this code prints what it does in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_elements(int i) {

    int j;
    short arr[3] = {0x01,0x02,0x03};
    char * ptr = (char *)arr;
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
        printf("\n %x,", *(ptr+j));
    }
}

main() {
    print_elements(4);
}
```

It prints out:

```
1,
0,
2,
0,
3,
```

Why is the output looking like this?

Some info which might be useful:

1. Byte ordering is little endian
2. The address of the first element of the array arr is 0x00
3. Short is 2 bytes

Answer (score 1):

Short takes two bytes of memory. that is 0x01 is stored as

`01 02 03`

your system is in little endian right to left  that is 1 0 2 0 3 0

when you use a char pointer and typecast array to be considered as char it to traverse's 1 byte at a time

your array for the pointer looks like this `1 0 2 0 3 0`

so in the loop for the array it get's printed in the order till 3 as you requested first four element to be printed.

Comment: So since it's stored as 01, 02 and 03 and ordered by little endian and since 1 2 and 3 of 01, 02 and 03 are the least significant bits, is that why it's technically ordered backwards for each array element? Therefore printing 1,0,2,0,3.

Comment: Yes. each element is stored one after the other for respective places arr[0] = 01 ( MSB is stored first that 0 then followed by LSByte i.e 1) so the series 10 20 30.

Answer (score 0):

It's printing the array elements byte-by-byte. Each short has 2 bytes on your machine and is stored in "little-endian" order (i.e., least-significant byte first). Since you've initialized the elements with the values 1, 2, 3, it prints, as expected, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0. (Actually, in your example you've asked it to only print the first 5 bytes, so the last 0 isn't printed.)

Comment: So to clarify.. it's printing byte by byte, but why does it treat the 0 and 1 in 0x01 separately? Aren't they one entry in the 3 entry array?

Comment: It doesn't "treat them separately". `0x01` is just `1`. But it's stored in 2 bytes (the size of a `short` on your machine). One of those bytes has the value 0, and the other has the value 1.

Comment: More questions to come! Have a very hard midterm tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

Not the clearest way to write code, but I'm sure the author had a good reason. Start by looking at arr. Assuming shorts are 16-bit signed integers here, your arr array elements look like this:

- 0: 00|01
- 1: 00|02
- 2: 00|03

In memory, this entire region in bytes looks like: 00|01|00|02|00|03

The ptr pointer is set to point to the start of this region of memory.

Next, your for loop goes through the loop five times (0..1..2..3..4). For each iteration, you're trying to print each byte from the region of memory, skipping the first region:

- (skipped): 00
- 0: 01
- 1: 00
- 2: 02
- 3: 00
- 4: 03

Comment: Nope. Look up "little-endian".